# Redirect to entity ID after entity create form submit with AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax

I have an AJAX entity create form and I want to redirect to that entity ID after I submit the form and create the entity, I know I can't use goto() because it's AJAX. I have the hook form alter for that entity already for some other customization of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `drupal_goto()` for form redirects. You should set the redirect in the form state.

```
function mymodule_myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // other code
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path';
}
```

Ctools provides a way to do a redirect in an AJAX callback, a function called [ctools_ajax_command_redirect](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ctools%21includes%21ajax.inc/function/ctools_ajax_command_redirect/7).

I found an example of someone using this function in a form callback that is AJAX:

```
function mymodule_custom_ajax_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //Close lightbox and redirect to the current page
  $path = $_SESSION['current_path'];
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($path);
  print ajax_render($commands);
  exit;
}
```

So, in your case, you would need to know the entity id in the submit handler, and you can get the uri with [entity_uri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x), which you can pass as the `$path` and that should work. Just load the entity object, and pass it to [entity_uri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x). It should return 'myentity/(id)' ex 'node/123', which you can redirect to.

Comment: looks like it is drupal_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state)  $form_id not $form

Comment: No, the first argument in a custom form submit handler is definitely $form.

Comment: How do I load the entity object? I think the API here says first argument is $form_id but I googled and see people use it like you said. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7.x